# Getting data from MySQL connection and showing it on a TextBox

Tags: c#, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have created a MySQL table. I can insert Data but now I'd like to get the saved data after I enter it into another tab's TextBox in my Windows Application in c# language.

I have coded the button "Refresh" to get the data, but I dont know if its correct or not. Basically I want to click it, get the data from the table, and post it at the textbox.

Here is what I got so far for the getting data part:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string clanname, date, type, rules, final;
        string connString = "Server=localhost;Database=request;Uid=root;Pwd=;";
        using (MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = mcon.CreateCommand())
        {
            mcon.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM requesttcw";
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    clanname = textBox1.Text.Trim();
                    date = textBox2.Text.Trim();
                    type = textBox2.Text.Trim();
                    rules = textBox2.Text.Trim();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help!
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The `Select` query in your question is fetching data from your `requesttcw` table.  You will want to read that data from your `reader` instance and add it to the appropriate text boxes.  For instance, you could do something like this to get data:

```
//textBox1 will hold the value of the first row and first column of your database.
textBox1.Text =  reader.GetString(0);
```

Updating the index in the `GetString` command above will change the column from which you are fetching data.  So, you will have to update that index appropriately to fetch the proper data from your table and insert to the right text box's `.Text` property.

I don't know what type of data you are dealing with in your table.  If the type is something other than `string`, you will want to use the appropriate `Get` function for the type, whether `int`, `double`, etc.  Check out the [MySqlDataReader reference page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqldatareader.html) for more types.

Depending on the frequency of which your table layout changes, you may also want to use `.GetOrdinal` to get data using your reader.  This command lets you specify a column name instead of its index.  The above call could be changed to:

```
//assuming "clanname" is a column in your database
textBox1.Text =  reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("clanname");
```

Lastly, in your example you used

```
while (reader.Read()) { ... }
```

This will loop through each row in your query result set.  I don't know how many text boxes you have or if you are looking for a specific format, but be aware that if you want to show data for a field from multiple rows in your text boxes, you will have to append to the `Text` property for each loop iteration.